# Replacing number between braces

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to do a replace in NotePad++ using regular expressions, but to no avail.

I'm trying to change

```
>{(number)}<
```

into

```
><
```

This is the XML I'm working with

```
<Financials>
   <IncomeStatement>
      <Revenue>{0}</Revenue>
      <OperatingIncome>{1}</OperatingIncome>
      <NetIncome>{2}</NetIncome>
      <BasicEPS>{3}</BasicEPS>
      <AvgSharesOutstand>{4}</AvgSharesOutstand>
   </IncomeStatement>
   <BalanceSheet>
      <CurrentAssets>{5}</CurrentAssets>
      <NonCurrentAssets>{6}</NonCurrentAssets>
      <TotalAssets>{7}</TotalAssets>
      <CurrentLiabilities>{8}</CurrentLiabilities>
      <TotalLiabilities>{9}</TotalLiabilities>
      <TotalEquity>{10}</TotalEquity>
   </BalanceSheet>
   <CashFlow>
      <OperatingCashFlow>{11}</OperatingCashFlow>
      <CapitalExpenditure>{12}</CapitalExpenditure>
      <FreeCashFlow>{13}</FreeCashFlow>
   </CashFlow>
</Financials>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Notepad++, you need to escape braces, as they're considered [special characters](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Search for `>\{\d+\}<`, replace with `><`.

Answer (score 3):

Try that regex

```
>\{[0-9]*\}<
```

use \ to escape {

> `Find what : >\{[0-9]*\}<`
>
> `Replace with : ><`

You should also not forget to check the Regular Expression option

Comment: He wants to change all number, it's in the question. Edit: it's \d

Comment: Edited my answer to replace all numbers, thanks @Kilazur

Answer (score 0):

Just match:

```
>{\d+}<
```

and replace with:

```
><
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/aU8uI5)

Comment: @RuiMartins, You can see in the demo that it _does_ work

Comment: @RuiMartins, Please let me know _how_ it doesn't work

Comment: You have to escape braces. I just found it myself on notepad++, it does work.

Comment: I mean, it does not work in NotePad++. But it works at regex101.com, taht's enough for me. Tks

Comment: You've got to remember that, even though SO tends to help people, its objective is to collect quality questions and answers. Your question is about Notepad++'s regex, I think the answer should take it in account.